# ¿Cómo puedo traer datos de un modelo a otro en Django para utilizarlos en la API?

Tags: python, django, rest, djangorestframework

Quisiera saber cómo puedo traer datos de un modelo a otro, ya tengo el Serializer del modelo creado y el endpoint también. Actualmente /result me muestra lo que tengo en UsuarioTestSerializer, y lo que me interesa es obtener el *nombre* de Test, actualmente solo tengo la *id* y necesito el *nombre* para poder mostrarlo en el front. ¿Cómo puedo obtener esa información? Agradezco si me pueden ayudar.

**class Test en models.py**

```
class Test(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url_imagen = models.URLField()

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.nombre
```

**class UsuarioTest en models.py**

```
class UsuarioTest(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    fecha_resultado = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    puntuacion_lograda = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __str__ (self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.usuario, self.test)
```

**class UsuarioTestSerializer en serializers.py**

```
class UsuarioTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UsuarioTest
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Función result en views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def result(request):
    serializer = UsuarioTestSerializer(data=request.data)
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Endpoint /result**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando solo las peticiones http de tipo `GET` y simplificando el problema al máximo. La solución sería agregar el campo en el serializer, por ejemplo:

```py
class UsuarioTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    test_nombre = serializers.CharField(source='test.nombre', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UsuarioTest
        fields = (
           'id', 'fecha_resultado',
           'puntuacion_lograda', 'usuario',
           'test', 'test_nombre',
        )
```

Es importante tomar en cuenta que el campo es marcado como `read_only` debido a que no es necesario especificarlo cuando vas a crear una instancia de `UsuarioTest` mediante el API. El valor es resuelto gracias al campo `source` que permite definir un valor obtenido a través de una llave foránea.

> **Nota.** Generalmente no es visto como buena práctica el especificar a fields como `__all__` debido a que dificulta ver a que campos esta teniendo acceso el serializer y cuales de ellos estan protegidos sobre operaciones de escritura.

Adicional al problema del serializer, me parece que la vista tiene un problema, y es debido a que la vista soporta dos métodos `get` y `post` hay un problema al considerar que esta siempre contiene información en `request.data`, situación que no es cierta en las peticiones de tipo `get`, ademas de al momento de crear el objeto, tal vez no quieras que el campo `id` sea determinado por el usuario , razón por la cual tal vez debería estar como `read_only`.

Otra forma de solucionar el problema original sería a través de serializers anidados, checa la [documentación](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) para más información aunque advierto que puede complicar un poco la lógica del serializer cuando se intenta crear un objeto a través de él.

Comment: Hola, al usar el read_only= true, afecta a mis peticiones post? Es que acabo de hacer eso que me colocaste y me tiró un error en mi front al intentar postear.

Comment: `read_only=true` lo que hace es decirle al serializer que este campo no es requerido cuando intentas crear una instancia o actualizarla, en caso de que no tuviera `read_only`, el serializer le exigiría que le pasaras el valor de  `test_nombre` al momento de crear un `UsuarioTest`. Puedes agregar  el nuevo error que te aparece para ver si hay algún otro conflicto.